# Understanding number of reads with snapshot attached to a collection after a single document is added

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Assuming in my app I've already read an entire collection with a snapshot listener.

If a document is added several seconds after an entire collection has been read does it triggers an entire collection read? or just the new document?

For example - a chat app between 2 people:

a collection (represents a chatroom) contains 4 documents (each represents a message) is already been read by a user, hence 4 reads. if the person on the other side sends another message, does this mean another 5 reads just went underway (4 old document, and a brand new one), resulting in a total of 9 reads? or only the new collection is been read, resulting in a total of 5 reads (4 from the beginning and another after the listener detected a new document inserted to the collection)?

Just to be clear all of the procedures described in the example (from the initial read) takes several seconds.

I can't find a solution or a similar question online, and I cant understand if in the firebase documentation there is an answer to it no matter how much I search there.

EDIT WITH SOMEWHAT OF AN ANSWER:\

After trying to figure out the exact numbers, I've run a test that resulted the following:

a collection with (say) 20 document (that a listener is attached to), that you add another 10 documents result in way more than 10 reads.

My conclusions for chat like implementations I would recommend using Firebase realtime database and not firestore. With a childeventListener you can extract and read only new messages without the need to re-read several models that you've already pre-loaded.

EDIT CODE I'VE RUN TO TEST:

```
collectionRef.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if(error!= null)
                    return;
                ArrayList<ChatMessage> justRead = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot : value){
                    ChatMessage data = snapshot.toObject(ChatMessage.class);
                    justRead.add(data);
                    Log.i(TAG, "msg: " + data.getMsg() + "\n" + "from cache:" +  snapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache());

                }
            }
        }));
```

LOG:

```
 2020-10-13 08:26:50.393 9275-9275/****** I/FirebaseLobbyViewModel: msg: first msg
    from cache:true
2020-10-13 08:26:50.402 9275-9275/****** I/FirebaseLobbyViewModel: msg: second msg
    from cache:true
2020-10-13 08:27:04.853 9275-9275/****** I/FirebaseLobbyViewModel: msg: first msg
    from cache:false
2020-10-13 08:27:04.853 9275-9275/****** I/FirebaseLobbyViewModel: msg: second msg
    from cache:false
2020-10-13 08:27:04.853 9275-9275/****** I/FirebaseLobbyViewModel: msg: third msg
    from cache:false
```

You can see that I've started the app with 2 msg in the collection, already been read thus accessed from cache, but after sending the third message all 3 messages are not obtained from cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshot listeners only download the document data for documents that have changed since the last snapshot.  They will not re-read the entire set of results again.  The unchnanged documents are delivered to your snapshot listener from memory, for as long as the listener remains added to the query.  If you remove the listener and add it again, it will cause all matching documents to be read again.

Comment: the thing is that we are not talking about a document update, we are talking in an listin event after a brand new document is added. in that case my tests show that the read count dosent equel the number of new documents, but greater than (at time it was twice as much), anyway thank you very much for responding

Comment: I am talking about exactly what you are talking about.  Only new and updated documents in the query result set will cause reads to be billed.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, i might've missunderstood you.
i've logged every snapshot metadata to see if its from cache and most of the time all snapshots return a false. it dosent mean they came from the server? hence a read operation was made? further i've left the app open for an hour on the chat, made sure the read count in firebase dashboard was stable, and after 10 messages, the read count advanced in 20.

Comment: Without seeing your code, the log output, the contents of your database, and the specific changes you're making, there's nothing I can advise.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what i realy want to understand, is that if a document isn't obtained via cache, it means it was obtained from server and thus count as a read?

Comment: Document snapshot that are immediately from cache are not counted as reads - the read originated locally and not from the server.

Comment: and if we know for a fact that the snapshot was not obtained from cache, we can assume a read action has accured?

Comment: Yes, the server is the only other source of data.

Comment: in this case we can clearly see in my Log that 2 documents that haven't been changed or updated, and was obtained from the cache several seconed before,  was obtained via server when a new document added, resulting in 3 reads and not just the 1.
thank you Doug! without your insight i would'nt understood it fully.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, it's customary on Stack Overflow to upvote and accept answers using the buttons to the left of the answer.

Comment: In your answear you state thet only the new document would get read, but in the log you can clearely see that 2 documents that already been catched and not been changed got obtrained from the server upon new document added to the collection. thus your answear is missleading. on the other hand, your comments and aprroving that document that we can know for a fact that wasent obtained via cache cost a read was very helpful, but i cant upvote a comment.

Comment: after revisiting this, the fact that 3 documents got obtained from the server, dosent neccecraly count as reads. anyway, thank you once again for your time

Answer (score 1):

after trying to figure out the exact numbers, i've run a test that resulted the following: a collection with (say) 20 document (that a listiner is attached to), that you add another 10 documents result in about 20+ reads (more then 10 that's for sure). my conclutions for chat like implementations I would reccomend using Firebase realtime Database and not firestore. with a childeventListiner you can extract and read only new messages without the need to re-read several models that you've already pre-loaded.