# Does it count as a second read?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of items in Firestore. To display them on the screen, I use a query and a SnapshotListener for real time updates. As per my understanding, I need to pay a read for each document I read.

When I click on an item, I navigate forward to the item details screen. In this case, I have another (separate) SnapshotListener that listens to a single document (clicked document). Is this considered another read? Or the item is read from cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already discussed by @Doug Stevenson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64321374/18265570)

> Snapshot listeners only download the document data for documents that have changed since the last snapshot. They will not re-read the entire set of results again. The unchanged documents are delivered to your snapshot listener from memory, for as long as the listener remains added to the query. If you remove the listener and add it again, it will cause all matching documents to be read again.

That means, it will not be considered as read until there are changes made to the document (like updating, deleting). It will read from memory when the documents are unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for answering but in the linked answer, it is said that "*The unchanged documents are delivered to your snapshot listener from memory, for as long as the listener remains added to the query*". But I wasn't asking about the listener that was attached to a query, but the second one, the one that reads the item details. So it's about the second listener, not the first one.

Comment: @JoanP. You haven't specified how your screens work nor have you provided code samples. As you are using the Android SDK, local data persistence is enabled by default. This means that with the limited information you have provided, Roopa's answer is accurate as in most cases the local cache will still contain the data you desire. In your situation, try not to disconnect the results listener or destroy the results screen as you show each item's details. You don't want to have a user accidentally tap the wrong entry, go back, wait for the  results to load, and then select the entry they wanted.

Comment: @samthecodingman There's is nothing special in displaying the items. A simple list with 10 items. My concern is, if I attach a new listener for reading the details, is that consider another read? As per my understanding, it's a new lister. Or it doesn't matter the number of listeners, the data is always read from the cache?

Comment: @samthecodingman If don't remove the listener it will always stay active between all screens, right? Is that a good practice in Android?

Comment: As covered above there is no way to guarantee that "the data is **always** read from the cache". The only way to do it would be to disconnect from the Firebase server with `goOffline()` but that doesn't make sense for your use case. If the data is cached, the data will come from the cache. If the data has been updated on the server, the fresh data will be read. Regarding my other point, I didn't say leave the listener active for all screens - just when using the parent (results list) and the child (item details). Destroy it once you are not displaying either screen.

Comment: samthecodingman Thanks for elaborating the answer. @JoanP. I hope you got the required inputs. Let me know if you are looking for something else?

Comment: @RoopaM In short, it doesn't matter how many listeners I use, if the data hasn't changed, I always get the data from the cache. Is that correct?

Comment: @JoanP. Yes you're right. As long as document exists in the cache and you are reading from it you will not be charged.